# I am trying to align the equations on the "=" signs

Tags: equations, align

Can you spot the error(s)?

```
\begin{align*}
$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n-\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n \\&=\Big[\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)-\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)\Big]F_n$

$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n-\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n\\&=\Big[\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big]F_n$

$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n-\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n\\&=\sqrt{5}F_n$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n\\&=F_n$
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Do not put dollar signs in an `align*` environment. The beginning of `align` starts math mode  by itself. A good editor would have shown you this with syntax highlighting and stuff.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You do not need $$ inside align.

Comment: Not the error...however, instances of `\Big` should be `\Bigl` or `\Bigr` depending on whether it applies to a left or right grouping symbol.  Also, no blank lines should appear in a math environment.

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed the dollar signs.  The error is a runaway argument?  I'm not sure why.  The code worked before I added the align.

Answer (score 2):

List of changes:

1. Got rid of `$` inside `align*` environment, as noted by Alice.
2. Got rid of blank lines in `align*` environment
3. Removed one instance of `\\`, so as to move right-hand side of equation to top row
4. Changed instance of `\Big` to `\Bigl` or `\Bigr`, as appropriate
5. Added documentclass and packages so as to turn a code snippet into an MWE.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n &=\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)-\Bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)\Bigr]F_n
%
\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n\\&=\Bigl[\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr]F_n
%
\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n-\Bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n\\&=\sqrt{5}F_n
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\Bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Bigr)^n\\&=F_n
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is slightly better than mine thanks to the removed `\\ `. I wanted to edit because “Changed instance of `\Bog`” instead of `\Big`, but the edit was too small and the website's interface rejected it xD On a sidenote, I persist in saying that a few spaces in that math code would make it more readable.

Comment: @AliceM. You are certainly right that breaking the code into bite size chunks makes it more readable, as long as "a few spaces" doesn't mean "blank lines" as that makes the code uncompileable.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that while working on it xD Your “%” lines are a nice touch.

Comment: That is almost it but how do I get the math to the right of Fn to be on the left?

Comment: By the way, you both are an AMAZING help to me right now.  presenting in a few hours and trying to work out the alignment.

Comment: So I moved the \\ to the proper places and the alignment is finished and ready to present...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Same basic suggestions as in [Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384506/5001), with the following additional ideas:

- use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` to size the round parentheses and square brackets;
- place the `n` exponents closer to the closing parentheses; and
- insert some extra bit of whitespace (in the amount of `\,`) between the large fractions and the closing large parentheses/brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page block parameters suitably
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\newcommand\n{^{\!\!n}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n
    -\biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n 
&=\biggl[\biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)
    -\biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\biggr] F_n
  \biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n
    -\biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n\\
&=\biggl[\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr]F_n
  \biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n
    -\biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n\\
&=\sqrt{5}\,F_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\biggl(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n
   -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\biggl(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\biggr)\n\\
&=F_n
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can add spaces and linebreaks almost to your liking in maths. This might make the code longer, but also easier to read and edit.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \Bigl(
        \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n - \Bigl(
        \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n \\
    &= \Bigl[
        \Bigl(
            \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
        \Bigr) - \Bigl(
            \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
        \Bigr)
    \Bigr] F_n \Bigl(
        \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n - \Bigl(
        \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n \\
    &= \Bigl[
        \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr] F_n \Bigl(
        \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n - \Bigl(
        \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n \\
    &= \sqrt{5} F_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \Bigl(
        \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \Bigl(
        \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}
    \Bigr)^n \\
    &= F_n
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why when you are writing an example you make it complicated. The problem will be solved easily when you write the necessary elements only.

To align 2 formula with a common character (like =), use `&` beside it (`&=`) when you are using `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   y &= x + a \\
   z - b &= c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this is what OP actually did, but the problem lies elsewhere (see the other answers).